# How can I get out of the screen select thing in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

A while ago I was using Chrome Dev Tools and I must have done something to turn the screen on the left, where it normally shows a part of your normal screen, into a screen where it showed my screen, but with a different resolution. So I could, for example, select a type of Iphone and it would show me the website in that resolution.
My problem is, that I want to switch back to the normal Chrome Dev Tools, but cannot figure out how. I have been looking around and not found a way to disable this feature again.

Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Press the second button in devtools toolbar to the left of `Elements`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to click the second button from the left in the DevTools toolbar as highlighted in the image below. That'll get you back to the normal view.

[image: Where the button is]